# Remove UIBezierPath with animation which added earlier

Tags: ios, swift, cabasicanimation

In my UICollectionViewCell, I've added a border via UIBezierPath with animation which is as below.

```
class AnimalSelectionCollectionCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    ...
    let shapeLayer: CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        let path: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(
            roundedRect: contentView.bounds.inset(by: UIEdgeInsets(top: 2, left: 2, bottom: 2, right: 2)),
            byRoundingCorners: .allCorners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: contentView.bounds.size.width, height: 0.0))
        shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
    }

    func setData() {
        ...
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 1.0
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        contentView.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    }

    func startAnimation() {
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = AppColors.Text.selectedName.cgColor

        let animation: CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
        animation.fromValue = 0.0
        animation.toValue = 1.0
        animation.duration = 0.5

        shapeLayer.add(animation, forKey: "myStroke")
    }
}
```

On selection of `UICollectionViewCell` I'm calling `startAnimation()` method which draw border with animation. Now, on on select again I want to remove that border with animation on reverse order (i.e. from 1.0 to 0.0).

How can I remove drawn path with animation?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming [`allowsMultipleSelection`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618024-allowsmultipleselection) is true, you can check `isSelected` and do different things depending on it:

```
func startAnimation() {
    if isSelected {
        showDeselectionAnimation()
    } else {
        showSelectionAnimation()
    }
}
```

Also consider overriding `isSelected` and putting this logic in its `didSet`, instead of having a `startAnimation` function. `isSelected` would be automatically set by UIKit.

Then, put your original code to show the selection animation in `showSelectionAnimation`. For the deselection animation, do something similar, but reverse `fromValue` and `toValue`. At the end of the animation, you should also set the stroke color back to clear, so that everything is back to the state before you called `showSelectionAnimation`.

```
func showDeselectionAnimation() {
    let animation: CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
    animation.fromValue = 1.0
    animation.toValue = 0.0
    animation.duration = 0.5
    animation.delegate = self
    shapeLayer.add(animation)
}

...

func animationDidStop(_ anim: CAAnimation, finished flag: Bool) {
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
}
```

Comment: Working smoothly as I expected. But at last, Drawing went away suddenly after appearing again. Can we fix it?